# jQuery/JS keeping count of selectivity plugin boxes for tag limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins

I'm currently trying to find the best (easiest) way to do the following.

I have 2 input boxes on my page and each has a data attribute of **data-cnt**. This starts with 0 and goes for however many boxes are on the page.

```
<p><span id="bomtags" data-powertip="" style="width: 150px;" data-cnt="0"></span></p>
<p><span id="bomtags1" data-powertip="" style="width: 100px;" data-cnt="1"></span></p>
```

As with the example above, I only have 2 boxes (0 and 1).

Currently I am keeping up with the limit count like so:

```
var tagLimit = 0;
var theOptions;
....more code within here....

_itemRemoveClicked: function (event) {
    tagLimit--;

    this.remove(this._getItemId(event));
    this._updateInputWidth();
    $.powerTip.hide();

    return false;
},
....more code within here....

_open: function () {
    toolTip(false);
    $('#' + this.$el[0].id).data('powertip', '<p style="top: -10px; position: relative;">Max limit of ' + this.options.limit + ' tags reached!<br/>Delete a tag in order to add again.</p>');

    if (this.options.showDropdown !== false) {
        if (tagLimit != this.options.limit) {
            console.log(this.$el.attr('data-cnt'));
            this.open();
        } else {
            toolTip(true);
        }
    }
},
....more code within here....

_resultSelected: function (event) {
    if (tagLimit < this.options.limit) {
        if (this._value.indexOf(event.id) === -1) {
            this.add(event.item);
            tagLimit++;
        } else {
            this.remove(event.item);
            tagLimit--;
        }
    }
},    
....more code within here....

if (tagLimit != this.options.limit) {
    //console.log('opened');
    console.log(this.$el.attr('data-cnt'));
    this.open();
} else {
    //console.log('hit');
    toolTip(true);
}
```

The **this.options.limit** houses the *MAX* number allowed tags in the box.

The **this.$el.attr('data-cnt');** is the value for the data attribute of that current selected box.

```
$('#bomtags').select3({
    items: cities, //['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: 'No permissions selected',
    limit: 3, //<--- the custom jQuery option
    tokenSeparators: ['|']
})

$('#bomtags1').select3({
    items: cities, 
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    bgColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    placeholder: 'No color selected',
    limit: 3, //<--- the custom jQuery option
    tokenSeparators: ['|']
});
```

Now that works just fine if I only have 1 box on the page. But if I have multiple boxes on the page then the count gets off course.

[image]

In the GIF animation up above, you see that in the first box when I add 3 tags it tells me on the 4th tag that 3 have already been selected and is the MAX. Then you see me try to insert 1 tag in the 2nd box but gives me an message of already chosen 3. Once I delete one form box 1 I can add another to box 2. This can go on and on where one box can have 3 tags while the other is stuck with nothing (because the **tagLimit** had already been reached).

I'm trying to figure out a way in order to keep the limit count for **each** box that's on the page but can not seem to come up with a solution.

If you need to know, I am using the jQuery plugin for the tags called [Selectivity](https://arendjr.github.io/selectivity/). However, I created the **limit** option myself as it did not include anything like that out-of-the-box.

Comment: It looks like the `tagLimit` variable is global or at least globally scoped for every instead of the plugin. Try `this.tagLimit` (or rather `this.tagCount` seems like it would be a better name) instead.

Comment: Indeed, it seems tagLimit is globally scoped.

Comment: @JasonP can you post an example (in code) of what you are saying?

Comment: Using **this.tagLimit** in place of **tagLimit** yielded not being able to add any tags to any box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that @JasonP meant this:

```
$('#bomtags').select3({
    items: cities, //['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: 'No permissions selected',
    limit: 3,
    tagLimit: 0, //<--- added custom jQuery option
    tokenSeparators: ['|']
})

$('#bomtags1').select3({
    items: cities, //['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    bgColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    placeholder: 'No color selected',
    limit: 3,
    tagLimit: 0, //<--- added custom jQuery option
    tokenSeparators: ['|']
})
```

The code above is where I placed the **tagLimit** option instead of a *global* variable that it used to be **(var tagLimit = 0;)**.

And all **tagLimit** are turned into **this.options.tagLimit**.

Worked just fine after that :)

Thanks for the push in the right direction, Jason.